# Do helper classes get mixed into the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a homecontroller, will the home_helper.rb get mixed into the controller class?

I'm assuming so as it gets access to the request object somehow.

Answer (score 1):

No, helpers do not get mixed into controllers. You can hack rails but your best bet is to just include the method in `application_helper.rb`

This seems to be the best hack:

http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/47-Using-Rails-helpers-from-controllers-or-anywhere-you-want