# Which class, specifically, do view helpers get mixed into?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything I read says that view helpers get mixed into views, but **which class, specifically** do they get mixed into?

References:

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#view-helpers
2. [Why can private helper methods still be accessed in views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835367/why-can-private-helper-methods-still-be-accessed-in-views)
3. [Do helper classes get mixed into the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726553/do-helper-classes-get-mixed-into-the-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller has a [`view_context`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L75), which is an instance of [`view_context_class`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L51), which is (by default) an anonymous subclass of `ActionView::Base` created by [`ActionView::Base.prepare`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb#L173). The helpers are mixed in to these view context classes.

The view context is also the place where the controller instance variables "magically" become instance variables in the view.

Comment: Nifty!  I was trying to read `ActionView::Base` but wasn't really getting anywhere.  Thanks.